# The phrase order to convey the order of events

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

I have this sentence:

> When (or As?) a node **matching** the anchor “Results” **is visited**, the subsequent nodes will be regarded in the scope of the context which begins with this anchor.

I doubt if I can say it as

> When a node **is visited** which **matches** the anchor “Results”, the subsequent nodes will be regarded in the scope of the context which begins with this anchor.

In the second sentence I want to imply that **matching** occurs after **visiting**, while I think the first sentence doesn't imply this.

Am I right?

By the way my original sentence was:

> By visiting a node which matches the anchor “Results”, the subsequent nodes will be counted in the scope of this context.

But I wasn't sure about its structure.

Answer (score 2):

The original sentence is more clear in this situation. It also has the advantage of conveying the fact that visiting occurs before matching. You could try substituting "which" with "that" if you wanted to make the sentence sound slightly better.

Comment: Thank you, just I wasn't sure about the structure of the sentence as I asked it in http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60176/preposition-at-the-beginning-of-the-sentence-after-by

Comment: Glad to be of help!